# define the method 'each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

OK so,  I know that there is hundreds questions that are talking about that.
I know what this error message means, and I know how to deal with that.

My question is : Is there a way to force the nil class to return an empty array?
My second question : Would it be safe ?

Thanks
Sebastien

Comment: You can define `each` for `NilClass`, but it's very ugly solution. If I were you, I would stick with `(array_or_nil || []).each { |e| #code }`

Comment: Can you elaborate little more about your use case.

Comment: Why not to add `to_a` to the values that may be `nil`? It seems clearer

Comment: Don't patch `NilClass`, return an empty array instead of `nil`.

Comment: All those responses are really helpful, thanks a lot.  I definitely give up the idea of patching 'nil'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Of course, you could patch *nil* (there is always only one *nil* object in Ruby thread, so you could patch it, and not NilClass):

```
def nil.each
  puts 'Hey'
end

nil.each #outputs 'hey'
```

2) But you should **never** do things like that, because it could break a lot of things inside a lot of libraries and even in Ruby itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like `@products`..try ternary operator

```
@products = @products.present? ? @products : []
```

Yes it's safe if you handle it properly using empty and check the relevant values that you need before you proceed ahead or save them

Answer (score 0):

You can patch the class where you're calling each on:

```
class SomeItem
  def each(&block)
    [] unless super(&block)
  end
end
```

Or patch Enumerable directly, but i'd be leery of touching core classes that way.